/ç/ after high vowels in Hexagonal French
I've often noticed that French speakers from France have a certain "off-fricative" on high vowels, typically emphasized ones (e.g. sentence-final). You can hear it clearly on the interviewer's éviter and Paris in the first sentence of this video.
It sounds to me like the voiceless palatal fricative /ç/, though it might be better be called a voiceless vowel when one thinks of the articulation: if you produce /e/ or /i/, for instance, and then stop vibrating your vocal cords while holding all else in position, you get this sound. But /ç/ is close enough to represent it if we don't want to contemplate voiceless vowels.

How common is this? The other speakers in the video don't do it, although they also don't have much opportunity — in my experience it's most common with the highest vowel /i/, and they only have word-final /e/ in their responses.

Is it associated with a particular dialect or demographic?

Does it carry any pragmatic force? For instance, does it in fact signify emphasis, a hanging question, an ellipsis...?



Could this particular instance be an artifact introduced by the digital recording? I often heard it on the TV news, back in the time of the analog sound encoding, when the mike was held outdoors. People exhibiting this speech habit in face-to-face conversation do exist (kind of a whistling sound following i or closed e endings), although they are extremely few in my experience, compared to its occurrence on the phone, radio, TV or Teams,

Also, note this whistling will not be produced if the syllable is linked: les pièges à touristes à évitersh ? A Parish ? but Les pièges à touristes à éviter-à Parish?

@FrançoisJurain I don't think it's the audio / recording, either in general (I've heard it often enough in person and in a variety of audio recordings) or in this instance (the audio seems clear to me, it only affects those vowels, and other speakers aren't doing it). Definitely agreed about it not appearing when linked and that her pause after éviter is what enables it here.

I've always called it the nha nha nha factor. In other words, very BCBG.

@Lambie Sounds offensive and un-French. How do you pronounce this "nha nha nha"? Is it like ña ña ña?

See this past question: Words ending on i/u, spoken with (IPA) ɪç – is there a system?

@sumelic Ah oui, je me souvenais vaguement que ça avait déjà été abordé, duplicate donc.

@jlliagre For nha nha nha, I interpret it as a synonym of la dee dah. For the duplicate... whoops! I even see that I upvoted that question and answer in the past.

@Luke Okay, la dee dah. I would use prout prout for it in French but this [ç] isn't particularly associated with pretentiousness.

Frankly, for me, I associate it with women, not men. The éviter one especially. Of course, nha nha nha is not French or even English. You'd have to hear me say it. And yes, it's la dee dah as Luke points out.

FWIW, I distinctly remember that I first heard it from a male professor, the first I'd had who was born in France. But I anecdotally would agree that I most often hear it from women...

The question and answer given in the Close announcement mention endings in i and u, not é like the present question.  I would expect devoicing to occur on closed vowels only, so i and é: the case for u is new to me. Also, they do suggest it started with newscasters, which matches my own experience of it (I'd even add, back in the time of analog TV).

@FrançoisJurain Interesting. As for /u/, it's as high as /e/. It is further back, though, so the palatal /ç/ approximation of that sound is unexpected; the first article that jlliagre linked to mentions that it gets paired with /x/ rather than /ç/. (I'm not sure why devoicing would be expected only on high vowels, but it does seem to be the case... perhaps I'll finish that article and find out.)

I'm not saying a and o could not be devoiced; I just wouldn't expect their devoicing to produce a sibilant w/out the speaker noticing it. I'd expect (wrongly it seems) this added constraint to imply the front of the tongue be s/what raised when pronouncing the vowel, hence "only i and é". Just my 2centavos: I'm no expert on these questions.

How common is this?
It is not uncommon but possibly relatively recent.
By exercizing with my own pronunciation, I realized that I was definitely producing that [ç] at the end of an emphasized, long oui, i.e. a ouiiiii...
Is it associated with a particular dialect or demographic?
I don't know. I guess most native French speakers do not notice it or do not pay attention to it. Non native are much more likely to notice it. It is perhaps more common among urban, upper class people. Journalists and women apparently too.
Does it carry any pragmatic force?
I don't think so, unless it's very long.
You'll certainly be interested by these papers:

Le dévoisement des voyelles finales.
Roberto Paternostro, Rassegna Italiana di Linguistica Applicata,
2008, 3 (40), pp.129-158. ffhalshs-00639082f


Merci×chh, entendu×chh : variation phonétique ancienne ou émergence d’une proto-particule en voie de stabilisation ?
Maria Candea, Jane Wottawa, Martine Adda-Decker, Lori Lamel.
Federica Diémoz, Gaétane Dostie, Pascale Habermann, Florence Lefeuvre.
Le Français innovant, 130, pp. 291-308, 2020, Sciences pour la Communication, 978-3-0343-4143-1. ffhal-02505343f


I think it goes to class and education, and possibly more women than men. That paper is very interesting.

Fascinating-looking papers indeed by the first pages. Will read!
